# How to align operators using alignat or someother environment?

Tags: math-operators, alignat

I'm trying to align equal signs and plus/minus operators in the following two equations:

S = 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 + 1/7 - 1/8 + ...

S/2 = 1/2 - 1/4 + 1/6 - 1/8 + ...

I want to align the fractions with the same denominators but can't seem to get it to work with alignat; Here's what I have so far:

```
\begin{alignat*}{6}
S &= 1 &- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} &- \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} &- \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} &- \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} &- \frac{1}{10} + \cdots\\
\frac{1}{2}S &= &+ \frac{1}{2} &- \frac{1}{4} &+ \frac{1}{6} &- \frac{1}{8} &+ \frac{1}{10}
\end{alignat*}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 15):

You have to understand that, in the `align` and `alignat` environments, for `n` alignment points, one needs `2n – 1`ampersands: the first one is to introduce a *ne* column (from the second column), the next one is for the alignment point inside its column. Also I removed the ìnitial `+` in the second row: the second alignment point is now the fraction, and I had to  add a pair of braces on each side of the `–`  in front of the fraction, so that it be considered by LaTeX as a binary operator with its own spacing, and not as the unary operator `sign`. (TeX has different spacing rules for binary and unary operators, in keeping with good typographic practice.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{6}
  S
    & = 1 & {} - {}
    & \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}
    && - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}
    && - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7}
    && - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9}
    && - \frac{1}{10} + \cdots\\%
  \frac{1}{2}S
    & = &
    & \frac{1}{2}
    && - \frac{1}{4}
    && + \frac{1}{6}
    && - \frac{1}{8}
    && + \frac{1}{10}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the unintiated, you may want to throw in a quick explanation what the `{}` ("empty math atoms") are doing. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Done. Not sure I'm fully clear for the unitiated…

Comment: +1. I've added a parenthetic sentence to explain that TeX's spacing rules for binary and unary operators are not the same. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Mico. I confess I have a tendency  to think everyone is more or less aware of typographical rules.

Answer (score 7):

You may find the following solution, which uses only the `array` package, instructive.

The `array` environment used in the solution has 23 [!] separate columns: 12 for the very first term and the numbers, and 11 for the `=`, `+`, and `-` symbols. This may seem like a lot of columns at first. On the up-side, notice that it's not necessary to insert `{}` ("empty math atoms") in various places just to inform LaTeX that the `-` and `+` symbols are binary rather than unary operators. A further upside is that you have full flexibility: If, say, you needed to add a third row, with entries in some of the columns that are left blank in the second column, you needn't change the setup at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r} % automatically in display math style
\newcolumntype{O}{>{{}}c<{{}}}       % "O" for "operator" ...
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % no need for extra intercolumn whitespace
\begin{array}{*{11}{RO}R}
S &=& 1 &-& \frac{1}{2} &+& \frac{1}{3} &-& \frac{1}{4} &+& \frac{1}{5} 
        &-& \frac{1}{6} &+& \frac{1}{7} &-& \frac{1}{8} &+& \frac{1}{9} 
        &-& \frac{1}{10}&+& \cdots \\[2.5ex]
\frac{1}{2}S 
  &=&   & & \frac{1}{2} & &             &-& \frac{1}{4} & &             
        &+& \frac{1}{6} & &             &-& \frac{1}{8} & &             
        &+& \frac{1}{10}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the new package `autoaligne`, augmented with a trick for removing the `+` sign from the first term in the second line.

The `\f` macro is just for slimming the input. It would be better if the empty terms could be denoted also with spaced operation symbols; alas, it doesn't seem to work. Nonetheless, the input for the alignment is much clearer than with so many `&` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

%% A trick for an empty delimiter
\newcommand{\makeempty}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1 \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathbin{\phantom{+}}}%
  \mathcode`#1="8000
}


\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\f}[1]{\dfrac{1}{#1}}
\aavcoeff{2.5}
\makeempty{V}
\definirseparateurs{\\}{+||-||V||=}{}
\autoaligne{
     S = 1 - \f{2} + \f{3} - \f{4} + \f{5} - \f{6} + \f{7} - \f{8} + \f{9} - \f{10} + \dotsb \\
\f{2}S =   V \f{2}        +- \f{4}        ++ \f{6}        +- \f{8}        ++ \f{10} + \dotsb
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the problem correctly, you could do it with a TABstack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}[2016-10-04]
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}
\tabbedShortstack[l]{ 
&S = 1 &- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} &- \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} &- \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} &- \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} &- \frac{1}{10} + \cdots\\ 
\frac{1}{2}&S = &+ \frac{1}{2} &- \frac{1}{4} &+ \frac{1}{6} &- \frac{1}{8} &+ \frac{1}{10} }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted to eliminate the `+` prior to the `\frac{1}{2}` on the 2nd line, then

```
\tabbedShortstack[l]{ 
&S = 1 -& \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} &- \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} &- \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} &- \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} &- \frac{1}{10} + \cdots\\ 
\frac{1}{2}&S = & \frac{1}{2} &- \frac{1}{4} &+ \frac{1}{6} &- \frac{1}{8} &+ \frac{1}{10} }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're ever in a pinch, you can "fill in the blanks" using `\phantom`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \begin{array}{l}
    \phantom{\frac{1}{2}}S = 
      \displaystyle 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{10} + \cdots \\
    \frac{1}{2}S = 
      \displaystyle \phantom{1-{}}\frac{1}{2} \phantom{{}+\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{1}{4} \phantom{{}+\frac{1}{5}} 
      + \frac{1}{6} \phantom{{}+\frac{1}{7}} - \frac{1}{8} \phantom{{}+\frac{1}{9}} + \frac{1}{10} \cdots
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```