# How to typeset a system of linear equations in LaTeX?

Tags: align

I need help in creating a system of linear equations as shown in the picture below:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
\begin{center}
\typesystem{
a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + \cdots + a_{1n} x_n = b_1,
a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 + \cdots + a_{2n} x_n = b_2,
\vdots\hfil&& \vdots\hfil          &&    \vdots\hfil    &&\vdots\hfil &&\vdots\hfil,
 a_{m1} x_1 + a_{m2} x_2 + \cdots + a_{mn} x_n = b_m
}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another `array`-based solution. By setting up the columns carefully, you're saved the tedium of having to enter `x_1`, `x_2`, thru `x_n` repeatedly in the body of the `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for columns with binary operators
\newcommand\vv{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for Times Roman fonts
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{c<{x_1} C c<{x_2} C c C c<{x_n} C l}
a_{11} & + & a_{12} & + & \cdots & + & a_{1n} & = & b_1 \\
a_{21} & + & a_{22} & + & \cdots & + & a_{2n} & = & b_2 \\
\vv    &   & \vv    &   &        &   & \vv    &   & \vdots\\
a_{m1} & + & a_{m2} & + & \cdots & + & a_{mn} & = & b_m \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

With `autoaligne` (and some trickery), see [How to align operators using alignat or someother environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339503/how-to-align-operators-using-alignat-or-someother-environment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

%% A trick for an empty delimiter
\newcommand{\makeempty}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1 \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathbin{\phantom{+}}}%
  \mathcode`#1="8000
}

\begin{document}

\[
%\aavcoeff{2.5}
\makeempty{V}
\newcommand{\cvdots}{\hfill\vdots\hfill}
\definirseparateurs{\\}{+||-||V||=}{}
\autoaligne{
  a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \dotsb + a_{1n}x_n = b_1 \\
  a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \dotsb + a_{2n}x_n = b_2 \\
  \cvdots   V \cvdots           VV \cvdots   V \cvdots \\
  a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2}x_2 + \dotsb + a_{nn}x_n = b_n
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JoB `autoaligne` is quite a recent package, so you may need to update your TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg So I guess this is not suitable for files intended for arXiv?

Comment: @thrope I'm afraid so, but the package has no dependency, you can just upload it along with your document.

Answer (score 8):

Solution based on `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{@{}*{7}{c@{}}}
    a_{11} x_1 & {}+{} & a_{12} x_2 & {}+ \cdots +{} & a_{1n} x_n & {}={} & b_1\\
    a_{21} x_1 & {}+{} & a_{22} x_2 & {}+ \cdots +{} & a_{2n} x_n & {}={} & b_2\\[-2pt]
    \vdots     &       & \vdots     &                & \vdots     &       & \vdots\\
    a_{m1} x_1 & {}+{} & a_{m2} x_2 & {}+ \cdots +{} & a_{mn} x_n & {}={} & b_m
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The curly braces in `{}+{}` and `{}={}` ensure the proper spacing around binary and relational operators.
- `[-2pt]` makes `\vdots` a little more symmetrical.
- `@{}` in the array specification removes the column sep.
- It is not clear to me, what "without symbol { " means.